# How to place <hr> to the right of an image?

Tags: html

I'm having trouble doing my homework with an HTML exercise. Basically I have to place multiple images in different locations on the screen/body but the problem comes from placing a line "hr" element to the right of the image..mine is being placed under it. Here are the photos with my progress and the exercise. I would be glad if someone could help me. Have a great day!

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDFV.jpg "Exercise"

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPy9I.jpg "My Progress"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ES 8</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="erba.jpg" width="10%">
    <hr>
    <img src="erba.jpg" width="30%">
    <img src="erba.jpg" width="10%" align="top">
    <div><hr align="left" width="20%"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is <hr> tag required? instead of this you can use border property

Comment: It isn't specified in the exercise, so I guess I can use border but I don't know how to use it in order to get the desired outcome. Do you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.upper img{
  width:15%
}

.lower{
  display:flex;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  margin-top:1rem
}

section{
  flex-basis:calc(100% / 3);
}

section img{
  width:100%
}

section:nth-child(2) div:first-child img{
  width:25%
}

section:nth-child(2){
    margin:0 1rem;
}

section:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2){
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  padding-top:1rem
}

section:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) img{
  width:80%;
  border: 2rem solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">
<img src="https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/fullhd/Green_Grass_Background_Texture-682.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="lower">
  <section>
    <img src="https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/fullhd/Green_Grass_Background_Texture-682.jpg"/>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div><img src="https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/fullhd/Green_Grass_Background_Texture-682.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/fullhd/Green_Grass_Background_Texture-682.jpg"/></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://pics.freeartbackgrounds.com/fullhd/Green_Grass_Background_Texture-682.jpg"/>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because by default most elements including `<hr/>` and `<div/>` are full-width boxes - or blocks stacked on top of each other. Read a bit more about the [box-model of  CSS elements here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model).

Taking it out of that `<div/>` and changing the `<hr/>`'s CSS to `display: inline-block` will add it to the side because it will set it as "inline" to the images. Keep in mind this will only work if it actually has room - so elements widths and borders and margins put together <= 100%.

You can also achieve the same effect with a transparent `</div>` where you just set one of its border to be visible instead of using `<hr/>`.

However, looking ahead at the rest of the exercise as well you will probably want to look at at some general layout elements such as [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid). They make positioning things in the page a whole lot easier once you get the hang of them.